# Как проверить равна ли строка подобному значению?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Приходит элемент `value` равный разным значениям. 
Если числовые - выполняю одно действие но если `value = [41 TO 80]`

то надо разбить эту строку на два числа, и выполнить с ними разные действия.
Разобью с помощью `split`

но как выполнить проверку что строка содержит `[число TO число]`?
попробовал вот так))

```
if(value.match(/\[[\d/g]\sTO\s[\d/g]\]/)==null) //действие
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
/\[(\d+)\s+TO\s+(\d+)]/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/UkDEz9/1).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подробности**

- `\[` - символ `[`
- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: одна и более цифр
- `\s+TO\s+` - один и пробельных символов, `TO`, один и пробельных символов
- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: одна и более цифр
- `]` - символ `]`.

Код на JavaScript:

```js
var s = "value = [41 TO 80]";
var m = s.match(/\[(\d+)\s+TO\s+(\d+)]/);
if (m) {
  console.log("Числа найдены: ", m[1], m[2])
} else {
  console.log("Другой формат...");
}
```

Comment: а для картинки какая-то утилита использовалась?

Comment: @Grundy https://jex.im/regulex/ + Paint